# Using list comprehension to create a list with single elements when using zip function

Tags: python, list, zip, list-comprehension

I have been trying to shuffle a list in specific manner:

```
def shuffle(card_deck):
shuffled = list()
deck_size = len(card_deck) // 2

lhand_deck = card_deck[0: deck_size]
rhand_deck = card_deck[deck_size: deck_size*2]

for i, j in zip(lhand_deck, rhand_deck):
    shuffled.append(i); shuffled.append(j)

return shuffled
```

To improve the perform for a larger deck, I decided to use list comprehension:

```
shuffled = [
    i
    for i in zip(lhand_deck, rhand_deck)
]
```

Now the the list contains tuple however I want it contain it single element:

```
shuffled = [0, 2, 1, 3]
```

instead of

```
shuffled = [(0,2), (1, 3)]
```

The * doesn't work it this case since it throws error. Is there any method to it or a loop can only be used? Thanks for help

Comment: You can use as mentioned in the duplicate `list(sum(shuffled, ()))`. This is of course just one of the several other ways in the duplicate

Comment: List comprehension will only marginally improve performance, and this improvement disappears if you cache the append methods manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to flatten the output instead:

```
shuffled = [
    i
    for t in zip(lhand_deck, rhand_deck)
    for i in t
]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the list of tuples:

```
shuffled = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(lhand_deck, rhand_deck)))
```

Which would give for this example list:

```
shuffle([1,3,5,2,1])
[1, 5, 3, 2]
```